# Issue in deletion of logs using logback

Tags: java, xml, logback, spring-tool-suite

Want to delete log file for every three hours with specified naming pattern `yyyy-MM-dd_HH-HHmmss`

Below is the code snippet:

```xml
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/spring-boot-logger.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}\_%d{HHmmss,aux}.log</fileNamePattern>  
    <maxHistory>3</maxHistory>   
</rollingPolicy>
```

Issue:
When I use two `%d` its get confusing which `%d` is for rollback and which is for naming pattern. I want to delete logs for every three hours with this naming pattern `yyyy-MM-dd_HH-HHmmss`.

Thanks in Advance!